# How to disable a RequestMapping when the application is running?

Tags: java, spring

Assume I have a `RequestMapping` like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/login")
```

How can I disable the path `"/api/login"` when the application is running?

Comment: why u need to disable after app running?

Answer (score 1):

You can have Spring Security or you can use Filter mechanism to filter request.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is logged in, and prevent them from going to the page, or use Spring Security or maintain a session.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this but theoretical one way to acchive this is having a toggle flag. This will work if you have only one instance. 
    If there are multiple instances the best way would be having thin in DB/store

```
private final AtomicBoolean enabled = new AtomicBoolean(true);

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/login")
public ResponseEntity login(){
    if(enabled.get()){
        login....
    }else{
        throw new LoginDisable();
    }
}

//method to enable/disable
```